# Exporting task of an instantiated module

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-dpi

I am trying to export several tasks to a C program via DPI-C. The tasks are defined in the module "my_subm" as:

```
module my_subm;
    task mytask1(...);
    ...
    endtask
    task mytask2(...);
    ...
    endtask
endmodule
```

And in my main module "main_mod", where "my_subm" is instantiated:

```
module main_mod;
    my_subm my_subm_i ();
    `include "dpic_exports.svh"

    initial begin
        ...
    end
endmodule
```

Where "dpic_exports.svh" is:

```
`ifndef DPIC_EXPORTS
`define DPIC_EXPORTS

export "DPI-C" task my_subm_i.mytask1;
export "DPI-C" task my_subm_i.mytask2;

`endif
```

When trying to compile it I get an error saying that in "dpic_exports.svh" my_subm_i is an illegal location for a hierarchical name.

What am I doing wrong?

What I need is these tasks to be available from the scope of "main_mod", as the C tasks that will access them are called from that module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export` statement has to be in the same location as the task/function being exported. Two suggestions: You can create wrapper tasks in your main_mod and export those

```
task mytask1;
  my_subm_i.mytask1;
endtask
task mytask2;
  my_subm_i.mytask2;
endtask
export "DPI-C" task mytask1;
export "DPI-C" task mytask2;
```

The other option is to put the `export` statements inside my_subn_i and use `svSetScope(svGetScopeFromName("main_mod.my_subm_i");` in your C code.

Comment: Saw the answer too late, but exactly how I ended up solving it (export statements inside submodule and using svSetScope in the C code). Accepting your answer now so that it may help someone else. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that a hierarchical reference is not allowed in an `export` statement.

Here's workaround. Apologies if I'm teaching you to suck eggs:

```
module my_subm;

    task mytask1(...);
    ...
    endtask
    task mytask2(...);
    ...
    endtask
endmodule

module main_mod;
    my_subm my_subm_i ();

    export "DPI-C" task mytask1;
    export "DPI-C" task mytask2;

    task mytask1(...);
        my_subm_i.mytask1(...);
    endtask

    task mytask2(...);
        my_subm_i.mytask2(...);
    endtask

    initial begin
        ...
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: Is that any different from what I said an hour earlier :)

Comment: No. But your answer wasn't there when I posted mine. It only appeared after posting mine (complete with "1 hour ago" tag). Hey - you got 10 points for it, I wouldn't complain! :)